# How to make radio buttons in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

I am trying to create few radio buttons for my form and I want the images to render exactly as in the image below.

[image]

I did below code but it does not render them from the standard magento form:

```
$fieldset->addField('country', 'radio', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('countrymodule')->__('region'),
            'name' => 'status',
            'values' => array(
                array(
                    'value' => 1,
                    'label' => Mage::helper('countrymodule')->__('scotland')
                ),

                array(
                    'value' => 2,
                    'label' => Mage::helper('countrymodule')->__('ireland')
                )
            )
        ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$fieldset->addField('country', 'radios', array(
                'label'     => $this->__('Select area'),
                'name'      => 'title',
                'onclick' => "",
                'onchange' => "",
                'value'  => '1', //if you select Scotland by default
                'values' => array(
                    array('value'=>'1','label'=>'Scotland'),
                    array('value'=>'2','label'=>'Ireland'),
                ),
                'disabled' => false,
                'readonly' => false,
                'tabindex' => 1
            ));
```